# How to create edd disocunt-code with programming?

Tags: wordpress, coupon, discount, easy-digital-downloads

I am working in wordpress edd plugin, in which i have requirement of create edd coupon code dynamically with specific amount, start date, end date and assign user to that code. I have not found any filter/action hook that will accomplish this task. Any help should useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDD provides `edd_store_discount()` function to add discount code programatically. You need to pass details as an array. Please check following example. In the following example, discount code `festival50` is created dynamically. This example discount code allows 50% discount. You can take following example and add other relevant parameters for the discount code.

```
$details = array(
    'name' => 'Festival',
    'code' => 'festival50',
    'type' => 'percent',
    'amount' => 50,
);

edd_store_discount( $details );
```